# Конструктор List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)?

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Возник вопрос следующего характера: согласно [офф. документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) с MSDN

-сам конструктор имеет следующий вид:

```
List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)
```

- т.е. список я параметризую неким параметром T, а в качестве аргумента могу передать элементы из указанной коллекции:

> Инициализирует новый экземпляр List, который содержит элементы, скопированные из указанной коллекции, и имеет емкость, достаточную для размещения всех скопированных элементов.

И как я понимаю параметр в `IEnumerable<T>` может быть отличным от `List<T>`

Тогда вопрос, почему возникает такая ошибка:

```
public class ParticleGenericClass<Particle> : IEnumerable
 {
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
  ParticleGenericClass<Particle> Pg = new ParticleGenericClass<Particle>();
      Particles = new List<int>(Pg) ;
```

ошибка возникает на строке:

```
Particles = new List<int>(Pg) ;
```

- > Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из `"ParticleGenericClass<UnityEngine.Particle>"` в `"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>"`.
  >   Upd: как я понял необходимо при реализации данного интерфейса сделать так:

  ```
   public class ParticleGenericClass<Particle> : IEnumerable<Particle>
    {


   IEnumerator<Particle> IEnumerable<Particle>.GetEnumerator()
  {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
  ```

  - но проблему это не решило

Comment: Что означает «проблему не решило»? Не компилируется в том же месте? С каким сообщением об ошибке? Не компилируется в другом месте? Вылетает в рантайме с `NotImplementedException`?

Comment: Да, не компилируется в том же месте с той же ошибкой

Comment: P.s изменения если что я сохранил

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать что с этим делать  -может возьму HashCode создаваемых  Particle

Comment: Ну, вопрос в том, а что вам _нужно_, чтобы было в коллекции? Если всё равно, можно хоть нулей туда положить.

Comment: Нет , мне нужно "отслеживать" частицы но если с самой коллекцией частиц взаимодействовать не получается - можно взаимодействовать с ней косвенно через их HashCode

Comment: Что-то мне не очень понятно, как взаимодействовать через хэшкод — ведь он может быть и одинаковым у всех. Ну ладно, это, думаю, уже следующая проблема.

Comment: Разве хешкод не уникален для каждого создаваемого объекта за исключение клонирования?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Подумайте, у вас возможно бесконечное количество разных строк, и только `2^32` различных хэшкодов. То есть даже на строках хэшкод в принципе не может быть уникальным.

Comment: @BadCats hash code не всегда уникален. То, что вам нужно(для уникальности) называется GUID. По идее, если вы переопределите GetHashCode на взятие HashCode из Guid, то будет работать(вероятность попадания там очень маленькая)

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: `GetHashCode на взятие HashCode из Guid` это нарушит смысл всего хешкода, так как для одинаковых элементов это будет генерировать разный хешкод, если хешкод генерится на основа гуида

Comment: Так мне это и требуется - уникальные значения генерируемые для каждого объекта На основе его Guid с помощью HashCode -  как я понял - и поэтому мне не подходит абсолютный Random с большим диапазоном - т.к потом этот HashCode - генерированный на основе  Guid и добавленный в качестве параметра коллекции (теперь уже - с чего и начинался вопрос) - я смогу "привязать" к каждому объекту типа Particle в другой коллекции - в момент его генерации. Т.е создаю Particle - беру его HashCode на основе Guid - добавляю в коллекцию и передаю ее как параметр.

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Просто запоминайте в каждом объекте его номер. Последний выделенный номер держите в статической переменной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что ваш класс `ParticleGenericClass<Particle> : IEnumerable` реализует `IEnumerable`, но не `IEnumerable<Particle>`.

А для `List<Particle>` нужно `IEnumerable<Particle>`.

То, что сам `ParticleGenericClass` является обобщённым классом с параметром `Particle`, не имеет значения. Нужна реализация (прямо или косвенно) `IEnumerable<Particle>`.

Проще всего, думаю, просто реализовать `IEnumerable<Particle>` в вашем классе `ParticleGenericClass<Particle>`.

---

Окей, новая проблема в том, что у вас неправильный тип generic-параметра.

Конструктор `List<T>` описан как принимающий параметр типа `IEnumerable<T>`. Видите, и там, и там `T`.

`T` не обозначает «короче какой-то generic-параметр». Как и с аргументами функций, одно и то же имя означает одну и ту же сущность. То есть, последовательность должна иметь *именно тот же тип данных*, что и список. А вы из последовательности `Particle`'ов пытаетесь построить список `int`'ов. Подумайте сами: каким образом компилятор узнает, как из `Particle` построить `int`?

Comment: Ок) только где об этом на MSDN ЯВНО было бы написано)

Comment: @BadCats: Хм. Вроде явно нигде не видел, да.

Comment: @BadCats думаю об этом не написано, потому что это больше правило работы дженериков. Сами подумайте: мы пытаеся привести  к IEnumerable с уточнением типа(т.е мы знаем, какого типа данные в нем лежат) тот IEnumerable, для котором мы не уточнили тип. А т.к это статический язык, для него это ошибка(даже если в IEnumerable лежит то же, что и в IEnumarable<T>

Comment: `Конструктор List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` - куда более явно то ещё?

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, где сказано, что `<T>` — это не просто «ну короче тут что-то должно быть», а одинаковым `T` соответствуют одинаковые типы? Явно я не встречал. (Хотя мне это казалось интуитивным всегда, по аналогии с формальными параметрами функций.)

Comment: @VladD мож до меня туго доходит. Но тут `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` явно указан тип Т для листа и тот же самый тип Т для перечисления. В чем смысл писать, что Т это Т и если Т используется в одном выражении, то это один и тот же Тип? Как то масло масляное получается :) Конечно, если не брать в расчет всякие вариантности

Comment: @tym32167: Я пытаюсь реконструировать логику ТС. То есть если видеть `<T>` как плейсхолдер в стиле «тут что-то должно быть», а не как формальный параметр, на который можно ссылаться, то тогда между разными `T` нету никакой связи.

Comment: А, я понял, то , что для меня прописано явно, является неочевидным для ТСа. Тогда все встает на свои места.